# Wordpress admin-ajax.php

Tags: php, functions, theme-development, wp-admin

I was thinking.. My admin-ajax.php file is slowing down my website a lot.#

What about if remove it? Is this file important enough? Would it be any security or funcionality issue after deleting it? Would my website be faster?

Any feedback would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File name should be `admin-ajax.php`

This file handles all the ajax requests. So, you should never remove this file.

Many features will stop working like autosave and many other that uses ajax if you remove this file.

Answer (score 0):

Removing your admin-ajax.php file will break your WordPress website. Look into what plugins are slowing your website down (via AJAX) and disable them & look for better alternatives.